# Azure ML Workbench File from Blob

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

When trying to reference/load a dsource or dprep file generated with a data source file from blob storage, I receive the error "No files for given path(s)".

Tested with .py and .ipynb files.  Here's the code:

```
# Use the Azure Machine Learning data source package
from azureml.dataprep import datasource

df = datasource.load_datasource('POS.dsource') #Error generated here

# Remove this line and add code that uses the DataFrame
df.head(10)
```

Please let me know what other information would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Encountered the same issue and it took some research to figure out!

Currently, data source files from blob storage are [only supported for two cluster type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/data-prep-supported-runtime-data-environments)s: **Azure HDInsight PySpark** and **Docker (Linux VM) PySpark**

In order to get this to work, it's necessary to follow instructions in [Configuring Azure Machine Learning Experimentation Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/experimentation-service-configuration).

I also ran `az ml experiment prepare -c <compute_name>` to install all dependencies on the cluster before submitting the first command, since that deployment takes quite a bit of time (at least 10 minutes for my D12 v2 cluster.)

Got the `.py` files to run with HDInsight PySpark compute cluster (for data stored in Azure blobs.) But `.ipynb` files are still not working on my local Jupyter server - the cells never finish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Azure Machine Learning team - sorry you are having issues with Jupyter notebook. Have you tried running the notebook from the CLI? If you run from the CLI you should see the stderr/stdout. The IFrame in WB swallows the actual error messages. This might help you troubleshoot.